# Ionic Capacitor -> node.js heroku -> not working with Socket

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, heroku, socket.io, chat

i was try to create a chat app using ionic and node.js ... backend is hosted on heroku

Socket io Declaration..

backend - const io = require('socket.io')(http);
frontend - this.socket = io("heroku url");

but still not working ... please help soon as possible

Comment: What are the errors are you getting? Have you declared `https` on the calls? Are the all sockets communications under SSL? Please, share more details!

Comment: Complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

After I run on web I was getting this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sellcar24hr.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0myUBB' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Then I searched for the solution .. I found one.

In the client-side front end I add:

```
this.socket = io(
    "heroku url",
    {
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']
    }
)
```

It works properly.